# Darktable: Is it possible to select only modified images in Lighttable view?

Tags: post-processing, photo-editing, linux, darktable

In Darktable, in the Lighttable view, is it possible to select/view only images that have been edited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Collect Images Darktable module]

Yes, using the **collect images** module on the left. Select 'history' from the left dropdown menu then double-click on 'altered' to show only those images which have been modified. Try Darktable's [user manual page](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch02s03s02.html.php) for a fuller explanation.

Additionally you can stack rules so you can narrow down searches, eg, by searching by a particular roll or folder and altered or unaltered.

I answered a [closely related question here, too](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/47271/8263).

Comment: This does not work for me on Darktable 2.6.3. After selecting either Altered or Unaltered, no pictures are shown…

Answer (score 3):

For a quick way to select the modified images in the current film roll, you can also open the [select] module on the right side. Click [select untouched] and [invert selection].

User manual reference: http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch02s03s05.html.php